# clojure bank account money transfer example

Tags: java, clojure, stm

I am new to `clojure` and I am trying to implement classic concurrency example aka `bank account transfer`. I want to implement it using `transactional memory`.

Here is an example in `java`

```
static class Account {
    private double balance;

    public synchronized void withdraw(double value) {
        balance -= value;
    }

    public synchronized void deposit(double value) {
        balance += value;
    }
}

static synchronized void transfer(Account from, Account to, double amount) {
    from.withdraw(amount);
    to.deposit(amount);
}
```

Not sure in my the implementation but it seems valid.

And here is my code in `clojure`

```
(deftype Account [balance])

(def account1 (Account. (ref 100)))
(def account2 (Account. (ref 100)))

(defn print-accs []
    (println " account 1 => " (deref (.balance account1))
             " account 2 => " (deref (.balance account2))))

(defn transfer [from to amount]
    (dosync
        (alter (.balance from) - amount)
        (alter (.balance to) + amount)))

(print-accs) ; 100 100

(transfer account1 account2 10)

(print-accs) ; 90 110
```

Is a proper example of using `transactional memory` or correct implementation of `bank account transfer` at all? Did I use `ref` correct for the field or should have used it for whole `Account` instance?

Comment: typo in `transfer`?  you pass in `from to`, but later use `account[12]`

Comment: oh indeed. Fixed

Answer (score 3):

You don't need `deftype`, but otherwise it looks good. I would simplify a little like so:

```
(def account1 (ref 100))
(def account2 (ref 100))

(defn print-accs []
    (println " account 1 => " @account1
             " account 2 => " @account2 ))

(defn transfer [from to amount]
    (dosync
        (alter account1 - amount)
        (alter account2 + amount)))

(print-accs) ; 100 100

(transfer account1 account2 10)

(print-accs) ; 90 110
```

One thing I'd recommend is to [review The Clojure Cheatsheet](http://jafingerhut.github.io/cheatsheet/clojuredocs/cheatsheet-tiptip-cdocs-summary.html) and always keep a browser tab open to it.  The links lead to more detailed info on ClojureDocs.org, [such as that for `dosync`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/dosync).  Enjoy!

## Update

For a single value like an account balance, there isn't much point in wrapping the balance in an `Account` record.  If you want to create a group of records that all have the same fields, you probably want `defrecord`:

```
(defrecord Account [name balance])
```

Most apps start off using a plain map like

```
(def joe-acct (ref {:name "Joe" :balance 100.00})
```

since it's simple & flexible. Later on, if you want to give a typename to maps that always consists of a name & balance, you can switch to

```
(defrecord Account [name balance])
(def joe-acct (ref (Account. "Joe" 100.00)))
```

`deftype` is considered "lower-level" and is rarely used nowadays. See:

- https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/defrecord
- http://www.rkn.io/2014/03/05/clojure-cookbook-polymorphic-functions/
- http://www.braveclojure.com/multimethods-records-protocols/

Comment: Well, I used `deftype` as I wanted to imitate creating a specific class for `Account`. That is why I asked the question whether should I stored `Ref` for `Account` instance of its `balance` field because I am not sure.

Comment: BTW, do you by chance know when the `Refs` are removed from the memory? By GC?

Comment: A ref is an "object" like any other, it is removed by GC when no longer referenced.

Comment: And what about `ref` for Account instance? I set `ref` for value - will there be a difference if I wrap `Account` into `ref` like this `(def ref-acc (ref (Account. 100)))`?

Comment: But if I have more fields than one - what approach I should use? whole class or just fields?